# Select attribute name with JsonPath

Tags: jsonpath

I'm consuming a JSON feed that returns a structure with an array of irregular objects - I can't predict what's in the array, and whatever is there will change over time. A simple example is

```
{
 "content":
   [
     {
       "person"  : "john"
     },
     {
       "car"  : "Audi"
     }
   ]
 }
```

The JsonPath query

```
$.content.[0]
```

returns the first object in that array. But, I need a jsonpath query that returns the literal NAME of the first property of that object, in this case I need the query to return "person". Is this possible?

Comment: Did you want just `JsonPath` or it's ok to add other things??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.content.[0].*~`

Tested on [JSON path](http://jsonpath.com/)

Comment: Please accept this additional "+1" for answering my question after 8 long years.

Comment: Please note that ~ works only with some implementations of jsonpath and is not part of the original [spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html). https://jsonpath.com/ use the library [JSONPath plus](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/#jsonpath-plus-)